# FindAll include more tables on sequelize query

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have the following query on my server controller where I bring all the data from al associate tables for my course:

```
db.Course.findAll({
  include: [
    // {model:db.Room, attributes:['id','DisplayLabel']},
    // {model:db.Period, attributes:['id','DisplayName']},
    { model: db.Subject, attributes: ["id", "Name"] },
    // {model:db.Schedule, attributes:['id','Day','StartHour','EndHour']},
    { model: db.Person, where: { id: db.Course.PersonId } }
  ]
});
```

The Course Model association is like this:

```
Course.hasMany(models.Schedule);

Course.belongsTo(models.Period);
Course.belongsTo(models.Room);
Course.belongsTo(models.Subject);
Course.belongsTo(models.School);
Course.belongsTo(models.Person);
```

The Problem is that I can't get the "Person" data cause sql log shows that the joins goes all the way through other table associate with the Person Model:

```
verbose: Executing (default): SELECT `Course`.`id`, `Course`.`Scholarship`, `Course`.`Level`, `Course`.`CourseType`, `Course`.`RecordStatus`, `Course`.`DeletedAt`, `Course`.`createdAt`, `Course`.`updatedAt`, `Course`.`PeriodId`, `Course`.`RoomId`, `Course`.`SubjectId`, `Course`.`SchoolId`, `Course`.`PersonId`, `Course`.`CreatedById`, `Course`.`UpdateById`, `Course`.`DeleteById`, `Subject`.`id` AS `Subject.id`, `Subject`.`Name` AS `Subject.Name`, `People`.`id` AS `People.id`, `People`.`RFC` AS `People.RFC`, `People`.`FirstName` AS `People.FirstName`, `People`.`LastName` AS `People.LastName`, `People`.`LastName2` AS `People.LastName2`, `People`.`Phone` AS `People.Phone`, `People`.`Cellphone` AS `People.Cellphone`, `People`.`Email` AS `People.Email`, `People`.`Birthday` AS `People.Birthday`, `People`.`RecordStatus` AS `People.RecordStatus`, `People`.`DeletedAt` AS `People.DeletedAt`, `People`.`createdAt` AS `People.createdAt`, `People`.`updatedAt` AS `People.updatedAt`, `People`.`RoleId` AS `People.RoleId`, `People`.`SchoolId` AS `People.SchoolId`, `People`.`TutorId` AS `People.TutorId`, `People`.`CreatedById` AS `People.CreatedById`, `People`.`UpdateById` AS `People.UpdateById`, `People`.`DeleteById` AS `People.DeleteById`, `People.Task`.`Title` AS `People.Task.Title`, `People.Task`.`Content` AS `People.Task.Content`, `People.Task`.`Grade` AS `People.Task.Grade`, `People.Task`.`OtherDetails` AS `People.Task.OtherDetails`, `People.Task`.`TaskType` AS `People.Task.TaskType`, `People.Task`.`RecordStatus` AS `People.Task.RecordStatus`, `People.Task`.`DeletedAt` AS `People.Task.DeletedAt`, `People.Task`.`createdAt` AS `People.Task.createdAt`, `People.Task`.`updatedAt` AS `People.Task.updatedAt`, `People.Task`.`KardexId` AS `People.Task.KardexId`, `People.Task`.`PersonId` AS `People.Task.PersonId`, `People.Task`.`CourseId` AS `People.Task.CourseId`, `People.Task`.`CreatedById` AS `People.Task.CreatedById`, `People.Task`.`UpdateById` AS `People.Task.UpdateById`, `People.Task`.`DeleteById` AS `People.Task.DeleteById` FROM `Courses` AS `Course` LEFT OUTER JOIN `Subjects` AS `Subject` ON `Course`.`SubjectId` = `Subject`.`id` INNER JOIN (`Tasks` AS `People.Task` INNER JOIN `People` AS `People` ON `People`.`id` = `People.Task`.`PersonId`) ON `Course`.`id` = `People.Task`.`CourseId` AND `People`.`id` = NULL;
```

Like you can see it brings the columns from the Task model, this is a table that origins from a m:n relation between Course and People

```
associate: function(models){
  models.Person.belongsToMany(models.Course, {through : Task});
  models.Course.belongsToMany(models.Person, {through : Task});
}
```

Also if I delete the table from the database just for debug purpose it does the same with another m:n relation. How do I exclude this from the join for just get data?

The Model Person, is you're wondering it saves all the different user: Student, Teacher, Father and it has a foreign key of Role Model that have this RoleTypes. That's why I have on Course Model the PersonId key that is in this case the Teacher and in the Task model for example, the PersonId refers to student user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query uses the `join` table `Task` because you define two associations between `Person` and `Course`. First one is `Course.belongsTo(Person)` and the second one is m:n relation. What happens is that Sequelize takes one of them into consideration - how would it know that you want the `belongsTo` association instead m:n? In order to omit this situation you could use `alias` in the associations

```
Course.belongsTo(models.Person, { as: 'Teacher' }); // example alias
```

And then, in order to retrieve `Course` with it's `Teacher` you would have to include the `alias`

```
db.Course.findAll({
    include: [
        { model: db.Person, as: 'Teacher' }
    ]
}).then((course) => {
    // course with Teacher
});
```

You can do the same with m:n relation

```
models.Course.belongsToMany(models.Person, { as: 'Students', through: Task });
```

And then you would use the `Students` alias in order to return all students of given course.

**EDIT**

In order to get column name other then `ModelId`, you need to define `foreignKey` or `otherKey` in the association. In your case in the m:n relation between `Course` and `Person` you want to have `StudentId` instead `PersonId`, you would have to use `otherKey`

```
models.Course.belongsToMany(models.Person, { as: 'Students', through: Task, otherKey: 'StudentId' });
```

Now the join table would have both `CourseId` (referencing `Course` table) and `StudentId` (referencing `Person` table).

**Note:** If you also define the m:n relation on `Person` model, remember to add equivalent option - `foreignKey`, like this:

```
models.Person.belongsToMany(models.Course, { as: 'Courses', through: Task, foreignKey: 'StudentId' });
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked, just one more thing. I tried to put the alias on the n:m relation as you said:

    models.Course.belongsToMany(models.Person, { as: 'Students', through: Task });

But it keeps appering in the database as PersonId, any clue?

Comment: I have edited the answer, with this solution you would get `StudentId` instead `PersonId`.